# Banner Ads not displaying with real unit ID

Tags: android, mopub

I am using MoPub in my application. I am trying to integrate banner and  banner ads with test unit ID works very well. But when i changed to real unit ID, banner is not displaying. I've got approved for MoPub Marketplace
P.S When i  added real banner ID to sample MoPub app from GooglePlay, i 've got "No ads found", status.`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Favorite");
    
    //reklamy
    moPubView= findViewById(R.id.mopub_view);
    moPubView.setAdUnitId("REAL UNIT ID");
    initalizeSDK("REAL UNIT ID");
}

private void initalizeSDK(String adUnit) {

    Map<String, String> mediatedNetworkConfiguration1 = new HashMap<>();
    mediatedNetworkConfiguration1.put("<custom-adapter-class-data-key>","<custom-adapter-class-data-value>");
    Map<String, String> mediatedNetworkConfiguration2 = new HashMap<>();
    mediatedNetworkConfiguration2.put("<custom-adapter-class-data-key>","<custom-adapter-class-data-value>");

    SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration= new SdkConfiguration.Builder(adUnit).withLegitimateInterestAllowed(false).build();
    MoPub.initializeSdk(FavoriteActivity.this,sdkConfiguration,initsSdkListener());
}

private SdkInitializationListener initsSdkListener() {
    return  new SdkInitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFinished() {

            moPubView.loadAd();

        }
    };
}
```